# div with 100% height and overflow:auto

Tags: css, html, overflow

I'm trying to make a page where I have 3 divs next to each other. The left and right div both have limited content, the center div will in many cases have more content than fits on the page. My goal is to give the center div a vertical scrollbar when needed. Should the left or right div actually ever have too much content, then the complete page should be scrollable.

this is how I want it to look:

[image]

```
<div id="everything">
    <div id="centeredDiv">
        <div id="left">text</div>
        <div id="main">plenty of content</div>
        <div id="right">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the css:

```
div {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

div#everything {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

div#centeredDiv {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div#left, div#right {
    width:100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

div#left {
    left:-100px;
}

div#right {
    left:200px;
}

div#main {
    width:200px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```

I tried to make a simplified jsfiddle example: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/CosmicAcidGuru/km8Xk/3/)

clicking the button will increase content in the center div. When the page is full, I'd like to have scrollbars for the center div, but they don't show up. Can anyone help me accomplish that?

I also wouldn't mind the 3 divs actually taking up the entire space up to the bottom of the page even when they don't have much content. Is there a way to make height:100% greedy?
Should I arrange my 3 divs differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be pretty close to what you're looking for it sounds like: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/km8Xk/4/).

I actually only changed one thing: <del>`height: 100%`</del> to `height:100vh`.

```
div {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

`vh` is setting it to 100% of the viewport height. It's a new CSS3 unit. Using it just depends on what sort of compatibility you need with it. All major modern browsers support it. And it seems to have pretty good support for a few generations back: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

CSS-tricks.com has a [good article](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) about Viewport Height.

Comment: let's say I have a fixed size header/footer, can I do something like 100vh - 80px ?

Comment: Not in CSS. Currently, CSS alone can not do logic or operations like that. You'd have to do it via javascript or jquery. It wouldn't be too bad to get the viewport height & the height of the footer (in case in the future it changes) and then subtract the two. That value would then get assigned as CSS (applied via javaScript).

Comment: The much easier option, would be to just change `100vh` to `85vh` (or some other value). That way it always gives a bit of room for the footer. But depending on how your design is layed out, it may not look the best. That'd just have to be your call.

Comment: thanks, I chose to just listen on the window resize event and then set the css height via js. I just hoped there would be a better way to do it.

Comment: You can use calc in css. height: calc(100vh - 80px);
https://jsfiddle.net/psbfr5rw/

Answer (score 1):

You can set `height:100%` to the `html` and `body` and a `min-height:100%` to the `div#main`. That makes your example picture trick.
See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zu7MS/1/

So,

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
div#main {
    width:200px;
    background-color: orange;
    overflow-y : auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `max-height` and `overflow: scroll` on the `#main` element

```
div#main {
    width:200px;
    background-color: orange;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/km8Xk/5/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing: `overflow-y:scroll` on the centeredDiv, and `overflow:hidden` on the right and left. I don't see that mentioned elsewhere, so if those divs can also have too much information, you'll want to set that style.

```
div#left, div#right {
  width:100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```